# Apache kafka lot of WARN log show Unexpected error

Tags: apache-kafka

I was running Kafka with 2 borker for cluster.

But I keep getting the WARN log.

I checked all my systems and there was no host using IP 10.8.7.1.

By the way, there was more IPs looks like from zookeeper or broker ?

If I shotdown on of Kafka, the WARNING log will be less

I am not familiar with Kafka and zookeeper, just getting starting and study

Any ideas?

Kafka version: 1.0.1

WARN log similar as below(get this kind of log about 10 secs),

```
[2018-04-19 09:13:08,342] WARN [SocketServer brokerId=0] Unexpected error from /10.8.7.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 369295616 larger than 104857600)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:132)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:235)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:196)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:545)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:412)
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:551)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:468)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that a Kafka producer on 10.8.7.1 is attempting to stream 0.369 GB of data in a batch instead of streaming. You may have to trace down the kafka producer and see whats going.

Hope this helps.